# Parsec or happy (with alex) or uu-parsinglib

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec, happy, uu-parsinglib

I am going to write a parser of verilog (or vhdl) language and will do a lot of manipulations (sort of transformations) of the parsed data. I intend to parse really big files (full Verilog designs, as big as 10K lines) and I will ultimately support most of the Verilog. I don't mind typing but I don't want to rewrite any part of the code whenever I add support for some other rule.

In Haskell, which library would you recommend? I know Haskell and have used Happy before (to play). I feel that there are possibilities in using Parsec for transforming the parsed string in the code (which is a great plus). I have no experience with uu-paringlib.

So to parse a full-grammar of verilog/VHDL which one of them is recommended? My main concern is the ease and 'correctness' with which I can manipulate the parsed data at my whim. Speed is not a primary concern.

Comment: This is a massive project. A Verilog parser is very complicated.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Supporting some part of verilog is good enough to show I wish to do with verilog during my Ph.D. but I want to continue this even after my Ph.D. So it's a really long term investment. I wish to know if Haskell fits the bill. I love this language.

Comment: So, what did you do in the end? Are you happy with your choice?

Comment: Do you mean the BNFC package? https://hackage.haskell.org/package/BNFC

Comment: yes.. this package also come with a executable command. Its really good.

Answer (score 20):

I personally prefer Parsec with the help of Alex for lexing.

I prefer Parsec over Happy because 1) Parsec is a library, while Happy is a program and you'll write in a different language if you use Happy and then compile with Happy. 2) Parsec gives you context-sensitive parsing abilities thanks to its monadic interface. You can use extra state for context-sensitive parsing, and then inspect and decide depending on that state. Or just look at some parsed value before and decide on next parsers etc. (like `a <- parseSomething; if test a then ... do ...`) And when you don't need any context-sensitive information, you can simply use applicative style and get an implementation like implemented in YACC or a similar tool.

As a downside of Parsec, you'll never know if your Parsec parser contains a left recursion, and your parser will get stuck in runtime (because Parsec is basically a top-down recursive-descent parser). You have to find left recursions and eliminate them. YACC-style parsers can give you some static guarantees and information (like shift/reduce conflicts, unused terminals etc.) that you can't get with Parsec.

Alex is highly recommended for lexing in both situations (<strike>I think you *have to* use Alex if you decide to go on with Happy</strike>). Because even if you use Parsec, it really simplifies your parser implementation, and catches a great deal of bugs too (for example: parsing a keyword as an identifier was a common bug I did while I was using Parsec without Alex. It's just one example).

You can have a look at my [Lua parser](https://github.com/osa1/language-lua) implemented in Alex+Parsec And here's the [code to use Alex-generated tokens in Parsec](https://github.com/osa1/language-lua/blob/master/src/Text/Parsec/LTok.hs).

EDIT: Thanks `John L` for corrections. Apparently you can do context-sensitive parsing with Happy too. Also, Alex for lexing is not required in Happy, though it's recommended.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your Lua parser.  It is helpful to see Alex in the flesh, and not just some toy examples from the documentation.

Comment: Much of the details concerning Happy in this answer are wrong.  Happy supports context-sensitive parsing (as parsers can be run in arbitrary monads).  Happy doesn't require Alex, you could use any lexer.  You could even do the lexing directly in Happy, although that wouldn't be recommended.