# Haskell parsing - Parsec with Alex

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec, alex

How can I use Alex as the lexer, then feed the tokens into Parsec for parsing?

Are there any examples?

I think Alex is better (and easier?) to use for lexical analysis than Parsec, but Parsec seems easier than Happy for parsing. They would probably make a good combination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can; see [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14775331/946226) by sinan to a related question, which also links to [example code](https://github.com/osa1/language-lua/blob/master/src/Text/Parsec/LTok.hs). Others have [taken that road](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2008-June/044685.html) as well.

Comment: Any more examples, please? Or some tutorial or article perhaps? Thanks.

Comment: That’s all I found. I think it is sensible to use Alex with parsec, but by no means the necessary best way and most users of parsec are  likely happy(sic!) to use Parsec lexemes.